# what wxYield() returns? Is it related to why my guauge is not updated?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using wxwidgets and I have a code like this:

```
    gaugeProgressFolders->SetRange(folderList.size());
    for(int i=0;i<folderList.size();i++)
    {
        ProcessOneSet(folderList[i]);
        gaugeProgressFolders->SetValue(i+1);          
        wxYield();
    }
```

The wxYeild doesn't update guauge. I am wondering why it is not working?

Looking at wxYield, I noted that it returns a bool but there is no documentation on what it returns.

Why my guauge is not update and how I can fix it?

what wxYield returns?

Comment: I searched the spec I can't find what it returns either.

Comment: It's been years since I did anything wx, and few memories remain, but the mere mention of `wxYield` brings up shudders and nasty memories of weird reentrancy errors that are near impossible to diagnose from the callstack and that take forever to fix. Yuck. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say what gaugeProgressFolders is.  Perhaps it is [wxGauge](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_gauge.html)?

In any case, why do you expect wxYield to magically update the display?

You have to write code to update the display.

Assuming various things about your code, you could write something like this:

```
gaugeProgressFolders->SetRange(folderList.size());
for(int i=0;i<folderList.size();i++)
{
    ProcessOneSet(folderList[i]);
    gaugeProgressFolders->SetValue(i+1);          
    // wxYield();  Don't call this, it does nothing

    // force the window to be repainted RIGHT NOW.
    Refresh();
    Update();
}
```

You might also try the following, for the sake of efficency and less flicker

```
   // force the gauge to be repainted.
    gaugeProgressFolders->Refresh();
    gaugeProgressFolders->Update();
```

Comment: You will have to provide a minimal sample program that builds and runs, showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a little late to respond, but I don't think wxYield() is the right call for your purpose of updating a gauge. Perhaps try:

```
gaugeProgressFolders->SetRange(folderList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < folderList.size(); i++)
    {
        ProcessOneSet(folderList[i]);
        gaugeProgressFolders->SetValue(i+1);          
        this->Layout(); //this being your window/dialog/frame
    }
```

Layout() forces the layout to redraw. It has been effective for me in the past.

Comment: Maybe this will work, but it also forces the sizers to recalculate their layout, which is unnecessary.  More efficient to call Refresh, Update directly.

Comment: True, it's not very efficient. In my experience, Refresh and Update don't glean the expected result, but I find that Layout does.

Comment: Refresh, Update forces the window to redraw with the same layout.  What other result are you expecting?

Comment: In my experience, nothing happens at all.

Comment: If that is true, you have a serious problem.  Provide a minimal sample program that builds and runs, showing the problem

Comment: I don't have a problem, I was simply suggesting a solution for the OP.

Comment: If your window does not redraw when you call refresh/update you have a serious problem.  The solution you have proposed for the OP is inefficient and is actually a workaround for whatever problem you are experiencing.